# How to create combinations (variant tree) of a table with several elements?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a Datagridview in a form, where some data about a product is entered. I need to create a variant tree showing all possible combinations, but i don't know how to get all possible combinations. For example let's say i have following table(datagridview): https://i.stack.imgur.com/tw7nX.jpg .

So possible combinations would be:

> **(Metal+Big+Red)**
>   **(Metal+Big+Green)** ...
>   **(Plastic+Very Small+Blue)**
>   **(Plastic+Very Small+Black)**

Can someone please help?

Edit: The example is there for understanding, the number of columns and rows with the data can be different, depends on what the user enters into the Datagridview. So i need a general approach how to get all combinations.

Comment: Do you want to make a new column with combination of other columns?

Comment: @SaeidAmini not really, i probably would have a list of strings with the combinations, but i just don't know how to programm to get all the combinations.

Comment: You need to post data as text, not as a picture, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
IEnumerable<string> GetAllCombinationOfFirst3Columns(DataGridView  dataGrid)
{
    for (int col_1 = 1; col_1 < dataGrid.Rows.Count && dataGrid.Rows[col_1].Cells[0].Value != null; col_1++)
        for (int col_2 = 1; col_2 < dataGrid.Rows.Count && dataGrid.Rows[col_2].Cells[1].Value != null; col_2++)
            for (int col_3 = 1; col_3 < dataGrid.Rows.Count && dataGrid.Rows[col_3].Cells[2].Value != null; col_3++)
            {
                yield return string.Format("{0}+{1}+{2}",
                                            dataGrid.Rows[col_1].Cells[0].Value,
                                            dataGrid.Rows[col_2].Cells[1].Value,
                                            dataGrid.Rows[col_3].Cells[2].Value,
            }
}
```

And recursive version:

```
IEnumerable<string> GetAllCombinationOfFirstNColumns(DataGridView dataGrid, int column0BasedIndex)
{
    if(column0BasedIndex==0)
    {
        for (int row = 1; row < dataGrid.Rows.Count && dataGrid.Rows[row].Cells[column0BasedIndex].Value != null; row++)
        {
            yield return dataGrid.Rows[row].Cells[column0BasedIndex].Value.ToString();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        foreach(string previousCombination in GetAllCombinationOfFirstNColumns(dataGrid, column0BasedIndex-1))
        {
            for (int row = 1; row < dataGrid.Rows.Count && dataGrid.Rows[row].Cells[column0BasedIndex].Value != null; row++)
            {
                yield return previousCombination + "+" + dataGrid.Rows[row].Cells[column0BasedIndex].Value.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but i need a more general solution, because the data can be entered in a lot of columns and rows, it was just an example for understanding.

Comment: @Kutuloo I've updated my answer with recursive version, which consumes an index of right-most column

Answer (score 0):

This method directly use `DataGridView`, you can pass your `DataTable`:

```
public List<string> GetNewValues()
{
    string material, size, color;
    List<string> newValues = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        material = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Material"].Value.ToString();
        size = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Size"].Value.ToString();
        color = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Color"].Value.ToString();

        newValues.Add($"{ material }+{ size }+{ color }");
    }

    return newValues;
}
```